# Accurev Workspace broken

Tags: accurev

So I have an accurev workspace that REFUSES to sync with the stream.

I have 99.999% of the files but there are a couple that were removed/added/changed what ever that aren't pulling to my workspace.

I have tried both of these solutions

[Restoring a workspace at accurev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331935/restoring-a-workspace-at-accurev)

[Forcedly update workspace in Accurev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395997/forcedly-update-workspace-in-accurev)

For some reason

D:MyWorkSpace\ accurev pop -O -R . D:\MyWorkSpace

Still won't pull the files I can clearly see in the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to force populate the file you have to do the above command but also give the fully qualified path to the file.

D:MyWorkSpace\ accurev pop -O -R .\subdir\thefile.cs

Answer (score 0):

What are the actual errors and exact command syntax (if using the CLI) that you are using?

Comment: What I posted is the exact CMD line syntax I used. The only way I could get the files to populate was to put in the fully qualified path to the file itself. When trying to populate the whole workspace it wouldn't pull the file. We even tried deleting the directory and populating it but it still didn't pull the missing files.There are no errors

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to use pop is to navigate into the workspace top directory and use "accurev pop -O -R .". However, this will only load files that exist as of the workspace transaction level. If there are newer files since that transaction, they will not be populated. It's very common to confuse update and populate.

In your instance, I recommend doing the following:

1. Run pop to download files and directories for the current workspace transaction level.
2. Run update to advance your workspace to current time. This will bring down new elements and newer versions of existing elements.

Also, include/exclude rules will impact what gets loaded into your workspace and any rules created in the workspace can override the stream configuration by omitting specific files and directories.

Comment: The syntax example was not the same as I wrote. Your message had:
<br/>
D:MyWorkSpace\ accurev pop -O -R . D:\MyWorkSpace
<br/><br/>
Unless this is a formatting issue, "D:\MyWorkSpace" at the end of the command should have produced a syntax error.
<br/><br/>
I had asked for the exact error message output. That's often useful in trying to help you.

Comment: It didn't produce a syntax error. It populated the entire workspace. It just didn't populate the missing files.